# Could not install packages into .netportable project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bottomnavigationview

I'm new to mobile development & Xamarin. I'm trying to install a 3rd party nuget package "BottomNavigationBar" to my portable project in Xamarin solution. But facing the below error while doing so.

Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I'm having Xamarin.Forms version 2.3.4.247, with Android target framework "Android 7(Nougat)". And I have Android SDK installed with API 24.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `BottomNavigationBar` is an `Xamarin.Android` platform specific library and can not be installed in a "portable" library, it can be installed in an `Xamarin.Android` application *or* library project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover) says this component targets `Xamarin.And`roid only so it will be impossible to install in the PCL project.

You should use a similiar plugin that targets `Xamarin.Form`, this plugin is called: [BottomNavigationBar.XF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF/)

You can see their source code here: https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF